# How to configure swagger-codegen to produce an all-args constructor for “allOf” classes at openApi3?

Tags: swagger, openapi, mustache, swagger-codegen

I want to modify the **pojo-mustache** template for **swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.24.jar** for a spec containing **allOf** to generate an all args constructor. **3.0.24** now produces `A extends B` (inheritance of some fields) whereas **2.4.14** used to produce just `A` (composition of all fields). So mustache markup to generate an all-args constructor will need to access the base class variable type/names. How is this achieved?

**More detail:**

Running  swagger-codegen 2.4.14 to generate Java language jaxrs-spec

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.14.jar generate -i composition_2.yaml -l jaxrs-spec
```

for the spec https://swagger.io/specification/v2/ assuming the example is in composition_2.yaml (extract below)

```
ExtendedErrorModel:
  allOf:     # Combines the BasicErrorModel and the inline model
    - $ref: '#/definitions/BasicErrorModel'
    - type: object
      required:
        - rootCause
      properties:
        rootCause:
          type: string
```

Uses the **pojo.mustache** (extract below from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.4.14)

```
public class {{classname}} {{#parent}}extends {{{parent}}}{{/parent}} {{#serializableModel}}implements Serializable{{/serializableModel}} {
```

This results in:

```
public class ExtendedErrorModel   {
  
  private final String message;
  private final Integer code;
  private final String rootCause;
```

The pojo.mustache can be enhanced to produce an all args constructor by adding:

```
public {{classname}}({{#vars}}@JsonProperty("{{name}}"){{& datatypeWithEnum}} {{name}}{{#hasMore}}, {{/hasMore}}{{/vars}})
```

This results in:

```
  public ExtendedErrorModel(@JsonProperty("message")String message, @JsonProperty("code")Integer code, @JsonProperty("rootCause")String rootCause) {
```

Running the same composition_2.yaml with swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.18.jar results in:

```
public class ExtendedErrorModel extends BasicErrorModel  {
  private @Valid String rootCause = null;
```

Running the **openApi3** equivalent with **swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.24.jar** has the same output as **swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.18.jar**.

The latest swagger 2 pojo.mustache https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators/blob/master/src/main/resources/handlebars/JavaJaxRS/spec/pojo.mustache#L6 and the openAPi3 pojo.mustache https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators/blob/master/src/main/resources/handlebars/JavaJaxRS/spec/pojo.mustache#L6 have the same class definition markup but the extends is unaltered from the 2.4.14 version suggesting the underlying swagger-codegen code has changed:

```
public class {{classname}} {{#parent}}extends {{{parent}}}{{/parent}} {{#serializableModel}}implements Serializable {{#interfaceModels}}, {{classname}}{{^@last}}, {{/@last}}{{#@last}} {{/@last}}{{/interfaceModels}}{{/serializableModel}}{{^serializableModel}}{{#interfaceModels}}{{#@first}}implements {{/@first}}{{classname}}{{^@last}}, {{/@last}}{{#@last}} {{/@last}}{{/interfaceModels}}{{/serializableModel}} {
```

How do I access the base class field type/names in mustache to generate an all args constructor? Note that at 2.4.18 and 3.0.24 the **-DdebugModels** of **swagger-codegen-cli** crashes when encountering allOf so the model can’t be examined.

Something like:

```
{{#models}}{{#interfaceModels}}{{#vars}}{{baseName}}
```